# Flagged Bounty Questions do not show up in flagged list

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty

I flagged the following question:

[how to find multidimensional array permutation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47070600/1011527)

with the following dialog box:

[image: question flag]

choosing the **should be closed..** radio (the question is overly broad and is essentially asking for teh codez). The question does not show up in my flagged list:

[image: flagged questions]

I have had this happen before and I re-flagged for moderation attention. That flag has yet to be responded to.

Why doesn't it show up? Is it because there is a bounty? If questions with bounties aren't allowed to be flagged should those links for flagging be removed from those questions?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you try to flag the question instead of close voting directly?

Comment: Because you cannot vote to close a question with a bounty @BDL, according to a warning delivered after you try to do so.

Comment: Right... and if you cast flags that are one of the close flags, they get converted to an actual vote... so it seems you should also get an error there that you can't do that rather than a silent failure...

Comment: Then that's most probably the reason why you can't flag it. Flagging as should be closed pushes the question to the close vote queue. How should that work if the question can't be closed? But I agree that an error should be shown.

Comment: I didn't get any error there @JonClements Instead the close dialog was immediately presented.

Comment: That's what I'm saying... once you get close *vote* privs, you can't use close *flags* anymore... So you should get the same error when you try as your flag is translated to a *vote* which can't work because of the bounty. If a bounty is preventing a really rather hideous question that must be closed from being so then you can use a custom flag... (but there's no absolute rules for when a moderator may remove a bounty)

Comment: Ah...I see, I didn't realize that @JonClements

Comment: @Jay you should probably at least get some warning/popup though rather than left to think it has happened. Given the number of bountied questions that get noticed, that need closing and the number of people who go the route of trying what you did though... it's probably a tiny corner case or it'd have been noticed sooner - so possibly a bug but not a show-stopping one.

Comment: As someone who has flagged several ill-fit bountied questions, it never once occurred to me to try to close-flag these posts, exactly because close-flagging went into a blind spot after 3k rep. So I concur with @Jon, probably an edge case that ~nobody have found yet.