# When is too broad not too broad?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers, needs-more-focus

A while back I flagged this question:

[Any way to add multiple images on Materialbox Materialize CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46495552/1011527)

As too broad. As it turns out it may have been a victim of the error I pointed out here:

[Flagged Bounty Questions do not show up in flagged list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358931/flagged-bounty-questions-do-not-show-up-in-flagged-list)

So, I raised another flag (**pending since 10/23/2017**) stating *"I flagged this as overly broad, but I do not see the flag appear in my flag list. In addition, the answers are link only and recommend resources rather than directly answering the question"*

Am I wrong in my assertions about the questions (too broad) and the answers (link-only and resources only) to the question?

Comment: Eh, it's more likely that it simply didn't garner enough votes to close it. the close queue is quite large.

Comment: You have close voting privileges.  You can't flag questions for closure, and haven't been able to for a very long time.

Comment: There is an option within the flag section to flag as should be closed, but with enough rep to cast close votes, those flags always turn into close votes, and close votes on bounty questions are always rejected.

Comment: I understand that @Servy but the flagging fell under the error mentioned in the other recent post to Meta.

Comment: @JayBlanchard well, no, the flag never occurred. so it couldn't have shown up under your flag list.

Comment: Your close vote was recorded and the question went trough review. The problem is that nobody reviewed it, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/17712430).

Comment: What's weird @KevinB is I just went and placed a close vote on the question and it did not throw the error.

Comment: @DonaldDuck it says "This item is no longer reviewable.
" and does not show that no one reviewed. Is that a bug?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the question, right now, does not have an active bounty..

Comment: Ah - I see @KevinB. Because the bounty has been "paid", right?

Comment: Right, it no longer has an available bounty, so it's free to receive close votes again.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The other question is about the fact that you can't vote to close a post that currently has a bounty.  This question doesn't have a bounty, so you can (and did) vote to close it.  You cannot flag it for closure, and it doesn't show up in your flag history, because you cannot flag *anything* for closure, and haven't been able to for many years.  You have close vote privileges, you *vote* to close, you don't flag for closure.

Comment: On the timeline you can see the review task was invalidated https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46495552/timeline as no one voted beyond your vote

Comment: @JayBlanchard It doesn't say explicitly that nobody reviewed it, but you can still see that that's the case. If someone would have reviewed it, it would have said "X reviewed this Y hours/days ago", like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/17803237).

Comment: Eh, i don't think that question is too broad anyway. The question is fine, the problem is the answers. If it isn't possible with the given plugin, that should be the answer.

Comment: The accepted answer only includes links to a github; *their* github (account) on top of that. That alone qualifies as being of very low-quality. If and when they decide to delete their account, that answer would have been null and void. Same thing goes for the other answer; link only. In either case, both answers should have contained a minimal amount of code.

Comment: can we even flag for very low quality anymore? only tool i see available is downvote.

Comment: You should be able to flag answers as being VLQ @KevinB

Comment: I don't see that as an option. spam, rude, not an answer, and flag for mod.

Comment: @KevinB I've often wondered why the "very low quality" option disappears after a while. IMHO, it should always be made available, regardless. Both those answers should have been marked as such.

Comment: I just checked another recent answer and the VLQ option is there. Is it because these have votes on them the option disappears? cc/ @KevinB

Comment: @KevinB I'd say "rude" comes closest *lol!* and for the question itself.

Comment: considering it's at 0 now and still not flaggable as VLQ, i'd assume it is time based.

Comment: @KevinB It should be flaggable as VLQ when at 0. I've always seen recently posted questions with +1/-1 equaling 0 and was flaggable. Maybe in this case being a bounty question, makes it react differently; it's hard to say.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Answers need to be negatively scored to be able to cast a VLQ flag, and I believe you can't cast them on posts older than 2 (or maybe 3) months.  It has nothing to do with bounties.

Comment: @Servy answers with no votes also have the VLQ option available.

Comment: Right ^ and shouldn't +1 / -1 cancel themselves out as being 0 (no vote)? @Servy

Comment: I think once a +1 has been placed @Fred-ii- the VLQ option goes away, regardless of -1's

Comment: well that doesn't make much sense @JayBlanchard I understand what you mean. So, it gets (one) +1 and many -1's, and still it doesn't make it VLQ/offer the option to flag as such?

Comment: That is what I believe happens @Fred-ii-

Comment: Giving my head a shake @JayBlanchard Oh well, *"c'est la vie"*.